# Azure APIM Setting multiple environment in one instance

Tags: azure, environment, azure-api-management

Currently I have created an Azure APIM Instance and the URL looks as below.

https://abc-test.azure-api.net

I want to use this APIM instance to Support Dev and QA environment. So I want to setup URL like below

https://abc-test.azure-api.net/dev/API/User/1

https://abc-test.azure-api.net/qa/API/User/1

So based on the environment variable, I will set the back end URL. Setting the back end URL is straight forward. But constructing above APIM URL is where I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would require registering API anew for every environment since the part right after hostname is API URL suffix and cannot be templetized. Alternatively you could have every operation in every API start with {env} URL template variable and pivot of that variable in policy to make a distinction. BUt that would make your URL look like https://abc-test.azure-api.net/API/dev/User/1 and will have you to have some env value for prod as well.

Answer (score 0):

An easy possibility is to specify your varying URL in the **API URL suffix** of the API like this: qa/API/User

And your Base URL can be specified in the **Web service URL**: https://abc-test.azure-api.net

[image]

This would require different APIs for different enviroments, but you can have a nice URL for PROD (without qa or dev in the URL) and clear URLs for testing enviroments.